# What happens if I send both pageviews and screenviews to my Google Analytics property?

Tags: google-analytics

As of today I'm sending what seems like two hits from each page of my SPA (built on Angular): one pageview and one screenview.

```
      // ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', 'screenview', {
        'appName': 'name of my site',
        'screenName': 'home'
    });
```

Reading the Google support forums it seems that:

> Google counts those separately and thus they don't appear in the same report

I'm trying to figure out if that's really the case and if there's anyway to confirm it.